# Parsing only valid string representation of list to list

Tags: python, list

I have a string, which I want to parse to list:

```
data = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']
```

parsing this to list(data) gives:

```
0 = {str} 'RED'
1 = {str} 'GREEN'
2 = {str} 'BLUE'
```

I have another string,
data = 'RED'

When calling list(data), I get:

```
0 = {str} 'R'
1 = {str} 'E'
2 = {str} 'D'
```

But, I need to throw an error in second case, because the string is not valid representation. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is `0 = {str} 'RED'`..?

Comment: Why are you passing `data` to `list` at all? Check `isinstance(data, list)`, `list` will turn anything iterable into a list of its elements.

Comment: @yatu This is what am I getting in debugger.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have input in string format in both the cases.

Comment: That's not what you've shown here. And it's probably not true; for `data = "['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']"`, `list(data) == ['[', "'", 'R', 'E', 'D', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'G', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'B', 'L', 'U', 'E', "'", ']']`

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? ``['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']`` isn't a string of a list, it is already a list (of strings). Also, ``list(data)`` never *parses* a string to a list. What *exactly* is your input, and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import ast
try:
    output = ast.literal_eval(data)
except:
    # This is block is executed when you have data like 'RED' only in the data variable
    # Keep the code here you want to execute otherwise
```